# PieChart using MPAndroidChart library in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mpandroidchart

I have successfully implemented the PieChart in my xamarin android project using the nuget package MPAndroidChart 3.1.0. When I try to set the colors I get the below error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Java.Lang.Integer>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Here is my code that im using:

```
  MikePhil.Charting.Data.PieDataSet pieDataSet = new MikePhil.Charting.Data.PieDataSet(datalist, "");
  pieDataSet.Colors = ColorTemplate.ColorfulColors;
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Java.Lang.Integer>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

means you have to convert `ColorTemplate.ColorfulColors` to `IList<Java.Lang.Integer>` Type first.

You can do it by using LINQ for simplicity.

```cs
using System.Xml;

...

MikePhil.Charting.Data.PieDataSet pieDataSet = new MikePhil.Charting.Data.PieDataSet(datalist, "");
pieDataSet.Colors = ColorTemplate.ColorfulColors.Select(c => new Java.Lang.Integer(c)).ToList();

...
```